# SVG text redraw incorrect when scaling in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, svg

When scaling an SVG element that contains text the text fails to redraw correctly. This problem only seems to occur in Safari (tested in Safari 5.1.7) on the desktop, it renders correctly on the iPad, and in the other major browsers, including the developer preview of Safari 6

See the following jsfiddle for a demonstration of the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/aBW25/

Viewers that experience the problem will not see the white text in the center of the red square, or the text will be rendered incorrectly.

Run the demo in a browser such as Chrome or Firefox to see the correct output.

Has anyone else experienced this problem or know of a way to get around it?

Thanks